# Creating multiple polygons with the same parameters (width,height)

Tags: qgis-3

I would like to create 32 18 meters wide and 800 meters long polygons next to each other within the attached polygon. This would be an agricultural experiment, the only thing I have to take into account is the area in the middle where we usually have inland waters. So I have to create 24 parcels left to it and 8 to the right.

I've tried to split my base polygon with the basic Editor tools, but I just can't figure it out how and wehere I can specify the hight and wide of my new polygons to be precise. After I created the first one I should only multiply it I guess.

I'm looking for a method in QGis.

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what you have tried, and how that was not adequate. With only thirty-two features involved, compute performance is certainly the lowest priority for evaluation.

Comment: thanks for your feedback! I did, I only tried the editor tools and you are right it's not about compute performance but  mine :) I can't find the perfect tool without help or I have to look for it for hours and the task feels simple

Comment: Not sure about QGIS3.0 but in QGIS2.0 there were vector tools in Geoalgorithms that could create a vector grid.

Check the Processing Toolbox for Vector Creation Tools

Answer (score 2):

Use the Create grid tool to create a line grid of the specified measurements. Be sure to select a CRS that uses meters. Specify the grid extent by using your layer as the extent.
[image]

Result:

[image]

Use Split with lines tool to split the polygon layer using the grid

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One helpful tool with QGIS3.0 would be `Geometry by expression` (in the Processing Toolbox | Vector Geometry).

**Step (1)** Create center point for each of 32 parcels. Assuming we can use the center of the lake (water reservoir) as referencing point;

[image]

The center x-coordinate of leftmost parcel is:

```
xL24 = x0 - ((24-1) * 18 + 1 * 18 * 0.5)
```

And the center x-coordinate of rightmost parcel is:

```
xR4 = x0 + ((4-1) * 18 + 1 * 18 * 0.5)
```

y-coordinates are the same as the center of the lake. (pond?)

**Step (2)** Apply `Geometry by expression` tool to the point layer (above).

```
bounds(make_line(make_point(x($geometry)- 18/2, y($geometry)- 800/2),
                 make_point(x($geometry)+ 18/2, y($geometry)+ 800/2)))
```